# ETC Split to non-hf wallet - lost?

Tags: wallets, hardforks, recovery, ethereum-classic

I think I may have lost all of my ETC.

Following Vitalik's instructions laid out here: https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/26/onward_from_the_hard_fork/

I created 2 new wallets on the same wallet client that was running on the Hard Fork - and ran the split contract between them. ETH got there but ETC never turned up and I assume the mistake is that the wallet was created only on the ETH chain.

Is there any way to recover these ETC funds?

Comment: That's exactly the idea of the splitter contract in your link: The ETH is in your new wallet, the ETC is still in the old wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up and sync a node on the ETC chain to see the ETC there. Also - if the original tx was not replayed on the ETC network, you will need to resend from your ETC node.